# How to create a Payment Method of type Card from Android using Stripe?

Tags: android, kotlin, stripe-payments

Once you have a Stripe object, you can call `stripe.createPaymentMethod`. However, there's no proper documentation on how to build the `PaymentMethodCreateParams` object, nor any code sample on Stripe GitHub samples.

`PaymentMethodCreateParams.create` requires a `PaymentMethodCreateParams.Card`, which can be built using `PaymentMethodCreateParams.Card.create("token")`. What is this token param? Is there any other way?

**EDIT**:
I'm trying to migrate from Sources to Payment Methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume you are using Stripe's `CardInputWidget` control? In this case, you would get the `paymentMethodCreateParams` from the widget like

````
            card_input_widget.paymentMethodCreateParams?.let { pmCreateParams: PaymentMethodCreateParams ->
                stripe.createPaymentMethod(pmCreateParams,
                    object : ApiResultCallback<PaymentMethod> {
                        override fun onSuccess(pm: PaymentMethod) {
                            text_info.text = "Card payment_method ID ${pm}"
                        }
                        override fun onError(e: Exception) {
                            text_info.text = "payment method creation failed "
                        }
                    })
            }
    ```
````

Comment: Thank you very much! Now I can find an example https://github.com/stripe-samples/mobile-elements-card-payment/blob/master/using-webhooks/client/android-java/app/src/main/java/com/example/app/CheckoutActivity.java

Comment: some optional item not mentioned in the "createPaymentMethod" method . Please can you update code with those optional item.

Comment: can you please share full source of code actually i am stuck on  createPaymentMethod importing issue.
Thanks in advance